# How to understand and mitigate the Evil DNS remote attack under linux systems?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, vulnerability, systemd-resolved

A new vulnerability has discovered on the `systemd` package called Evil DNS allowing the remote control of a linux machine. From the [security-tracker.debian](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-9445) , the debian Stretch , Buster and Sid are vulnerable. ( Also affect a various Linux distro with Systemd)

System check:

On Debian Stretch , my `systemd --version` is `systemd 232` before and after the system update.

The `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` command say that the `systemd-resolved` is disabled.

How to easily understand and mitigate the Evil DNS remote attack under linux systems? Does stopping the `systemd-resolved` service is sufficient to prevent the Evil DNS attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Ubuntu security notice](https://lwn.net/Articles/726645/), the issue only affects `systemd-resolved` (this can be confirmed by looking at the [patch fixing the issue](https://marc.info/?l=oss-security&m=149858648509403&w=2)). So a system which isn’t running `systemd-resolved` isn’t exposed, and stopping `systemd-resolved` is sufficient to prevent the attack.

This is the reason why the [Debian tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-9445) mentions “[stretch] - systemd  (Minor issue, systemd-resolved not enabled by default)”, meaning that while Debian 9 does include the affected code, it’s a minor issue and won’t result in a security advisory. You can receive notification of the fix in Debian 9 or later by subscribing to [the corresponding Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866147).